Win32 job objects and process creation from the windows shell (Explorer)
Windows 10 Pro x64 if it matters, 21H2 if it matters, though I've seen this behavior on Windows 7 Pro x64 as well.
So I'm looking at the windows processes using process explorer. What I notice is that some child processes of explorer.exe are created as part of a win32 job and some are not. explorer.exe itself is not part of a job. cmd.exe (started from explorer.exe) is not associated with a job. If the same exe is started from explorer.exe and again from cmd.exe - the process created from explorer.exe is associated with a new job object and the one from cmd.exe is not. So automatic new job association seems like explorer.exe related and not specific to the OS.
So the question: how does explorer decide whether to associate the process with a new job or not?
So far what I have found as a common setting between non-job associated processes and job associated processes is that non-job associated ones have the "Control Flow Guard" image flag Enabled, however this is not implemented on Windows 7.
EDIT 1
Some more findings. If the same process is started from explorer.exe from a network share (acking the security prompt) instead from ex. the local program files folder, the process is started without being associated with a job.
As to the practical problem... (This might need to go to stackoverflow. Let me know if I should reopen it there).
So far seems to be reproducible under Windows 7. Windows 10 seems OK.
I build an exe that happens to be started from explorer with a job. Then I do a ShellExecute shell api call to an xlsx file with the "open" operation. Excel (2016 Pro if it matters) opens and prompts a very "meaningful" message:
Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space.

- To make more memory available, close workbooks or programs you no longer need.
- To free disk space, delete files you no longer need from the disk you are saving to.

If at the start of my exe I check whether it is running in a job and if yes, restart it without one, then Excel opens correctly and displays the file.

Is there some practical problem you're trying to solve, or is this more about curiosity at this point?

Yes, there is a practical problem. Edited (edit 1) the question.
